# PHP OB_START which double quotes

Tags: php, json, ob-start

i'm using php on_start and ob_get_contents to echo html and store in a variable. However when I json encode and check the output it doesn't output the entire string. Could anyone help point out what I'm doing wrong

```
    ob_start();
   echo'<a href=\"javascript:pixlr.edit({image:\"http://mywebite.com/uploads/$photo\", title:\" $photoFileNameProper\", service:\"express\", exit:\"http://mywebsite.com/home\", method:\"get\", locktarget: \"true\", target:\"http://mywebsite.com/plixr.php\", locktitle :\"true\"});\" id=\"uploadedPhoto\" title=\"click to enhance photo\"><img src=\"images/editphotohover.png\"/></a>\"';

  $photo = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
```

I get only get the ending anchor tag
in the json encode output

Comment: Why are you doing it with `ob_start` when you could just assign it to a variable?  Replace `echo` with `$photo = ` and you're good to go.

Comment: @GigaWatt Assume the code as an excerpt of a larger file - where ob_start() makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to escape double quotes here

```
echo'<a href=\"javascri...
```

just write this:

```
echo'<a href="javascri...
```

**Double quotes are kept while in [single quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)!**

Additionally, note that [escaping within single quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) has no effect:

- `"\t"` renders as a TABULATOR character
- `'\t'` renders as `\t`

The [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) states this:

- To specify a **literal single quote**, escape it with a backslash (\).
- To specify a **literal backslash** before a single quote, or at the end of the string, double it (\\).
- Note that **attempting to escape any other character** will print the backslash too.

Therefore, how about this code:

```
echo'<a href="javascript:pixlr.edit(
                { image: \'http://mywebite.com/uploads/$photo\',
                  title: \'' . $photoFileNameProper . '\',
                  service: \'express\',
                  exit:\'http://mywebsite.com/home\',
                  method: \'get\',
                  locktarget: \'true\',
                  target: \'http://mywebsite.com/plixr.php\',
                  locktitle: \'true\'
                });"
         id = "uploadedPhoto" 
         title = "click to enhance photo">
         <img src="images/editphotohover.png"/>
         </a>'
        ;
```

Comment: Well, you still need to escape two things in single-quoted strings: `'` and `\\`

Comment: @KwaasiDjin Have a look at my appended answer. You need to escape the inner-inner-quotes.

Comment: @SteAp its still not working. For some reason it only picks the anchor tag <a/>